# Finally Action on PostSharp Exception aspect

Tags: postsharp

I got following situation

```
private volatile bool _inProgress = false;

public void DoSomethingStart()
{
  if(_inProgress == false)
  {
      foo.BeginInvoke(null, null); // DoSomething
      _inProgress = true;
  }
}

[CatchAllExceptionsFromHere]
private void DoSomething()
{ }
```

The aspects works so far. All exceptions are handeled from CatchAllExceptionsFromHere. But i want to set "_inProgress = false" in the finally clause of the aspect - so if DoSomething has finished "_inProgress" should be set to false. Since Attributes cant take any object - is there a workaround?

Thanks michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aspects can take values on the declaration to set property values or just like a constructor. What you want is an OnMethodBoundaryAspect and in the OnExit method (which fires even if an error has occured, so it's just like a finally) you want to set the value of _inProgress.

However, the aspect needs to be an instance aspect and you'll need to either import the _inProgress member or just introduce it so that the aspect has access to it. It depends on if your class needs access to it. If it does the have the aspect import the member. Read up on how to do these things with these links

- [Aspect lifetime & scope part 1](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-9-Aspect-Lifetime-Scope-Part-1.aspx)
- [Aspect lifetime & scope part 2](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-10-Aspect-Lifetime-Scope-Part-2.aspx)
- [Introducing members part 1](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-14-e28093-Introducing-members-and-interfaces-Part-1.aspx)
- [Introducing members part 2](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-15-e28093-Introducing-members-and-interfaces-Part-2.aspx)